# Web Worker slow response

Tags: javascript, performance, web-worker

I want to handle heavy process with Web Worker, and after some research I'm stuck to the response delay of my Workers.

To simplify I will admit I have only one Web Worker : I create a Web Worker, and I call `postMessage` with my data.

I pass my data with `ArrayBuffer` to avoid data transfer slowdown from copy.

I directly reply from my Worker with the same `ArrayBuffer` as data

Problem is the following : my `ArrayBuffer` is sent extremely fast from my main thread to every instance of my workers (something like 1-2ms), but the response is very slow (50 to 100+ ms)

Code is the following

Main thread :

```
 var now = performance.now()

 myWorker.postMessage(buffer, [buffer])  

 myWorker.onmessage = function(data){
  console.log(performance.now() - now) // 20 to 100+ ms
 }
```

Worker :

```
onmessage = function(data){
  // ~1 ms
  self.postMessage(data.data, [data.data])
}
```

I suspect my main thread to be slowed down by other processing so the handle of the message is delayed by this few millisecond, but I want to be sure my code is okay and this is not a known issue.

Comment: Since this is multithreading, you can't assume that when you post a message, the other worker will instantly receive it. There is no reason to think that there should be no delay since the browser can send the message to the worker at its own pace, once it's done with everything else. (Also, consider moving the `myWorker.onmessage = ` to before you do the `postMessage` just in case)

Comment: I'm okay with that, but why the sending is consistently fast (even with multiples workers and large queue of messages), whereas receiving is slow and with delays varying that much ? The thing is I have some dozens of 50ms tasks, so in the main thread, it could take several seconds to handle, and I supposed I could handle these 50ms tasks in multiples threads, but with a response of 100ms I don't know if is it worth it

Comment: I suspect the onmessage callback on my main thread is delayed because the thread is full, could you confirm this is not a code or worker issue?